# How to set default configuration for Sonata sonata_type_date_picker

Tags: symfony, configuration, sonata-admin

I know from [Sonata Data Picker documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/core/master/doc/reference/form_types.html#sonata-type-date-picker-and-sonata-type-datetime-picker) that field configuration for `sonata_type_date_picker` can be passed with :

```
$builder
    ->add('publicationDateStart', 'sonata_type_datetime_picker', array(
            'dp_side_by_side'       => true,
            'dp_use_current'        => false,
            'dp_use_seconds'        => false,
    ))
```

But, is it possible to set some default configuration at an application level in a yml or xml file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can achieve to set defaults for sonata's `sonata_type_datetime_picker` for application wide is to override the form type service for `sonata_type_datetime_picker` and in class parameter define your own class to handle defaults.

1) Create a service file in your bundle `form_types.xml` and override sonata's service like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="sonata.core.form.type.datetime_picker" class="Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DateTimePickerType">
            <tag name="form.type" alias="sonata_type_datetime_picker" />
            <argument type="service" id="sonata.core.date.moment_format_converter" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

In above service you can see i have defined a class that lies in `Acme\DemoBundle`

2) Create a class in `Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type` and name it as `DateTimePickerType` and extend this with sonata's `BasePickerType` class

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    /**
     * Here do what ever you need to change
     */
    $resolver->setDefaults(array_merge($this->getCommonDefaults(), array(
        'dp_use_minutes'     => true,
        'dp_use_seconds'     => true,
        'dp_minute_stepping' => 1,
    )));
}
```

3) Import your service file in main configuration file i.e `config.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: @AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/form_types.xml }
```

Full code demo visit [***Git Hub***](https://github.com/dianuj89/sonata-admin-override-datetimepicker-service)

Comment: Khalid, thank you for the answer. I put it in my workflow for the week. I give you a feedback soon.

Comment: Than you Kalid for your answer. I was wishing to just have to configure this in more convenient way, but service override works well.